# Classification model on Time series data

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification

I have time series data for n ids ans each id has features data from 2013.i have 3 classes.how do you classify data points into 3 classes..can i use classification model on time series data?if yes then  which classification model can i use for training and prediction.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Read about [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) (particularly [how to create a good example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) in order to get responses.

Comment: for time series analysis you could try using LSTM.